# Using jQuery to move a list's position up or down

Tags: jquery, css

I have a simple list which will consist of 1 or more rows.

I have a JavaScript variable which represents the number of rows the entire list should be raised.  Note that I am not looking to swap rows within the list.

For instance, if I raised it 2 rows, "third" will be positioned where "first" originally was, and "first" would be positioned two rows higher.

Ideally, I would like a jQuery solution instead of a native JavaScript solution.  Thanks

```
<ul id="myList">
 <li>First</li>
 <li>Second</li>
 <li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have a look at: http://api.jquery.com/index/ and http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/

Comment: By *raising the list*, do you mean moving the list itself around (i.e. changing the position itself) or changing the indices of its list items?

Comment: @m90.  insertAfter inserts elements (i.e. LI in the UL).  I wish to move the entire UL element up a distance equal to N times the height of a LI element.

Comment: @techfoobar.  Yes, the position, and not the indices of the list items.

Comment: Can you include an example? Like after raising the variable by 2,3,4?

Comment: @Clyde.  Raise by zero would be no change, raise by 1 would move each row up one row (so second is where first used to be and third is where second used to be, and first is above it's original position), raise by 2 would move each row up two rows (so third is where first used to be, and first and second are above their original positions by two rows)

Comment: I assume you are trying to change the position of the rows on the page.

Comment: @Clyde. Relative to it's parent, which for all practical purposes is the main page, so yes you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this **demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/n6UhP/1/

This assumes your list is absolutely positioned.

```
var liHeight = $('#myList li:first').height(); 

function moveUpBy(_numLIs) {
    $('#myList').animate({
        top: ($('#myList').offset().top - _numLIs * liHeight) + 'px'
    }, 'fast');
}

function moveDownBy(_numLIs) {
    $('#myList').animate({
        top: ($('#myList').offset().top + (_numLIs + 1) * liHeight) + 'px'
    }, 'fast');
}
```

Comment: Ah, perfect techfoobar!  I really had a difficult time communicating what I was trying to do.  Thank you for bearing with me.

Comment: I don't wish to animate it but have it instantly at the desired position.  I just changed "fast" to 0, and it seems to work.

Comment: If you dont want the animation, you can simply call `.css(..)` instead of `.animate(...)` - and remove the second parameter for speed. For ex: `$('#myList').css({ top: ($('#myList').offset().top - _numLIs * liHeight) + 'px' });`

Comment: Exactly on the lines of what I was thinking. +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change the order of the list items by manual interaction, I think the `jQuery Sortable` would be the best option.

Try this:

http://jqueryui.com/sortable

Comment: Thanks Xmindz.  Cool functionality, but not what I am looking for.  Wish to keep the order the same, but move the entire list up.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the main `UL` having position relative you can use jQuery `position` method to get find posion of each list item, and adjust negative margin accordinglly.

```
function moveList(itemIndex) {
    var top = 0 - $('#myList li').eq(itemIndex).position().top;
    $('#myList').animate({
        'margin-top': top
    })

}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/HcUhC/1/

Demo uses a fixed height parent with `overflow: hidden`, can change the over flow for different visual

Comment: Thanks charlietfl,  I will look into.  Any pro's or con's over techfoobar's solution?

Comment: my version doesn't rely on all items being same height. It works from the actual position of the item relative to the `UL`. Also doesn't require absolute positioning